# Is it best practice to cache Azure KeyVault ClientID & Thumbprint?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is it industry best practice to cache your ClientID, SecretId and/or Thumbprint to retrieve KeyVault secrets?

If possible is there a sample code for me to do it in C#?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to secure it the secret and the thumbprint. Essentially anything that can be used to access the resource. If you really want to, you can secure the client ID as well, but I haven't heard of anyone suggesting this or recommending this.

Per the Keyvault Overview:

**Azure Key Vault helps solve the following problems:**

- Secrets Management - Azure Key Vault can be used to Securely store and tightly control access to tokens, passwords, certificates, API keys, and other secrets
- Key Management - Azure Key Vault can also be used as a Key Management solution. Azure Key Vault makes it easy to create and control the encryption keys used to encrypt your data.
- Certificate Management - Azure Key Vault is also a service that lets you easily provision, manage, and deploy public and private Secure Sockets Layer/Transport Layer Security (SSL/TLS) certificates for use with Azure and your internal connected resources.
- Store secrets backed by Hardware Security Modules - The secrets and keys can be protected either by software or FIPS 140-2 Level 2 validates HSMs

I suggest reading through the referenced overview for keyvault and looking through the docs as well : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview